# Keeping score in a game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

My assignment for a my computing science class is to create a game.

So far I was able to add the shapes when called, and make them disappear when they are clicked.

I am having difficulty trying to figure out how to count the score (when the shapes are clicked or missed) and to change the game difficulty

**Here are some hints we received from the prof:**

**Keeping Score**

Keeping the number zapped and missed is a little tricky. The strategy needs to be:

- When the shape is created, give it a .click() handler so we can zap it when the user clicks.
- When it's created, start an animation that determines the time during which it can be clicked: at the end of the animation, we'll declare it missed.
- In the shape's click handler, remove it from the SVG and count it as zapped.
- When the animation is over, remove the shape from the SVG and count it as missed.

**To do this, we need to use more arguments on .animate():**

```
shape.animate(attributes, time, 'linear', callback)
```

We have see the first two arguments: new attributes, and how long the animation should take. We'll ignore the third argument and leave it as 'linear' (the default).

When the animation **is over**, Raphaël will run the function callback(). The callback argument gives us a way to run some logic at the end of the animation. For us, that's when the user has “missed”.

The initial setup for each shape will be:

```
shape.click(zap)
shape.animate(..., ..., 'linear', miss)
```

**Then in each of the miss and zap functions:**

- Remove the shape from the image.
- Add one to a variable keeping track of the total zaps/misses.
- Update the display of zaps and misses in the HTML.

[This is what I am trying to aim for](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiWhAHx2TW8)

---

```js
start = function() {
    difficulty = $('#howmany').val();
    figure = $('#choice').val();
    var SVG = $('svg');

 
    for (i = 0; i < difficulty; i += 1){
     x = Math.random() * 400
     y = Math.random() * 400
     if (figure == 'a') {
      shape = paper.path('M25,0 L50,50 L0,50 Z')
     } 
     if (figure == 'b') {
      shape = paper.rect(0, 0, 25, 25)
     } 
     if (figure == 'c') {
      shape = paper.circle(0, 0, 25)
     } 
     shape_attr = {
      'fill': '#F9B'
     }
     shape_move = { 
      'transform': 't' + x + ',' + y,
     }
     shape.attr(shape_attr)
     shape.animate(shape_move, difficulty * 1000)
     shape.click(zap)
  
     setTimeout(function(){
      SVG.find("circle").remove();
      SVG.find("rect").remove();
      SVG.find("path").remove();
     }, difficulty * 1000);  


    }
}  

zap = function () {
    this.remove();
}

miss = function () {

}



setup = function() {
    paper = Raphael('svg', 400, 400)
    $('#go').click(start) 

}

jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```

```css
svg {
  border: thin solid black;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

main {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/raphael-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="logic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Assignment 4: Zap 'em</title>
</head> 

<body>

  <h1>Assignment 4: Zap 'em</h1>

  <main>

    <div class="form">Difficulty:
      <input type="text" id="howmany" />
      Shape: <select id="choice">
      <option value="a">Triangle</option>
      <option value="b">Square</option>
      <option value="c">Circle</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button id="go">Start</button></div>

    <div id="svg"></div>

    Zapped: <p id="zapped"></p>
    Escaped: <p id="escaped"></p>
     
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I have so far.
If you guys can help me out with this, that will be amazing.

Comment: You'll need variables to count zaps and escapes and update them at the appropriate times. After you update them, then you can update the 'score' displays with the new values.

Comment: Java and Javascript are not the same thing.  They are as similar as Car and Carpet.

Comment: It tells you what you need to know pretty much. Have a variable zap and miss, and update those in your zap and miss funcs. Have a this.remove() in both. And also use jquery you update your miss and zap display to the value of miss and zap. You're pretty much there. Otherwise you need to be more specific about what error or bit you are struggling with.

Comment: @Ian Hi Ian, am i going in the right direction for my "miss" variable? Can I update the score by using the "if" statement like that?

Comment: This bit.. '#zapped' += 1 looks wrong, you would use jquery or something to update it's value. You probably don't want  shape == 'zap' as shape isn't a string (although it's possible some types convert). It may be something like shape.name or shape.type or something (you will need to examine the object for that, or set some variable on it yourself), plus I'm not really sure what you are trying to do there.

Comment: @ian I'm having trouble trying to keep score. Every time the user clicks on the shape, and the shape disappears, i want to count that click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a global variable to store zap clicks and difficulty

```
var zap_total = 0;
var difficulty = 0;
```

In start function, update difficulty

```
difficulty = parseInt($('#howmany').val());
```

When user click to zap, we increment zap_total and update zapped result

```
zap = function () {
   this.remove();
   zap_total++;
   $('#zapped").text(zap_total);
}
```

When time is out, we update miss score

```
...
    setTimeout(function(){
        SVG.find("circle").remove();
        SVG.find("rect").remove();
        SVG.find("path").remove();
        miss();
    }, difficulty * 1000);
...

miss = function () {
    $('#escaped").text(difficulty - zap_total);
}
```